# Go to already open tab in IE11

Tags: javascript

In Chrome and IE11, when the code below is executed the first time, it opens a new tab in the same browser, and navigates to that tab.
When it is executed a second time, in Chrome it navigates to that tab, but in IE11 it just makes the tab flash.

How might I get the IE11 tab to actually show on the second execution?

```
function RspHelp(varAnchor) {
var wrkHelpUrl = ""
wrkHelpUrl = '/../App_Pages/fA50_HELP/fA50_HELP.aspx'
var ws = wrkHelpUrl + "#" + varAnchor

window.open(ws, 'helpwindow')
window.blur()
window.focus(ws,'helpwindow')

return
}
```

EDIT:  based on the comments below, I decided to go with opening new browser instances, via the code below, which works fine in IE and Chrome.  A new browser instance is actually a better fit for the app, too.

```
wrkHelpUrl = '/../App_Pages/MyHelpPage.aspx'
var ws = wrkHelpUrl + "#" + varAnchor
winHelp = window.open(ws, 'helppage', 'height:700,width:950')
```

Comment: It's probably a browser setting that cannot be influenced with JS.

Comment: Window/tab behavior is browser-specific. Browsers may have different defaults, and users can change the behavior. You can't do anything about it.